# Apache HttpClient with limited waiters

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache HttpClient 4.5 and I want to configure the connection pool to limit the number of waiting threads. So if the pool is exhausted, it should allow up to *n* threads to wait for a connection (with some timeout), but any additional requests should immediately fail.

Is there a configuration option for that? If not, is there a clean way to [decorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) it with a semaphore to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

public class ConnectionPoolExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a connection manager with pool settings ,use it with your requirments
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100); // maximum number of connections in the pool
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(10); //maximum number of connections per route

        // create a HttpClientBuilder and set the connection manager
        HttpClientBuilder httpClientBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
        httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connectionManager);

        //closeableHttpClient
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = httpClientBuilder.build();

        // Use the httpClient for making requests
        
    }
}
```

I look in the decorator and the following should be helpful .because as far as i know there is no direct configuration option available in Apache HttpClient 4.x to limit the number of waiting threads in the connection pool

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager;

public class HttpClientExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // create a connection manager with the desired maximum connections
        PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        connectionManager.setMaxTotal(100); // set the maximum total connections
        connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(50); // set the maximum connections per route

        // Create a semaphore to limit the number of waiting threads
        int maxWaitingThreads = 10; // Set the maximum number of waiting threads
        Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(maxWaitingThreads);

        // Decorate the connection manager with the semaphore
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connectionManager)
                .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
                .addInterceptorFirst((HttpRequestInterceptor) (request, context) -> {
                    try {
                        semaphore.acquire(); // acquire a permit from the semaphore
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                })
                .addInterceptorLast((HttpResponseInterceptor) (response, context) -> {
                    semaphore.release(); // Release the permit back to the semaphore
                })
                .build();


        
        httpClient.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this is supposed to help.

Comment: The interceptor solution doesn't fail when the semaphore is maxed out. And `addInterceptorLast()` doesn't execute after the request.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up decorating `HttpClientConnectionManager` with a sempahore as a workaround for a [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77790620/1553851). This is done in 5.x, but the concept should work for 4.x with a little tweaking:

```
public class GuardedHttpClientConnectionManager implements HttpClientConnectionManager {
    
    private final HttpClientConnectionManager delegate;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;
    private final Timeout timeout;
    
    public GuardedHttpClientConnectionManager(HttpClientConnectionManager delegate, int permits, Timeout timeout) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(permits);
        this.timeout = timeout;
    }
    
    @Override
    public LeaseRequest lease(String id, HttpRoute route, Timeout requestTimeout, Object state) {
        LeaseRequest lease = delegate.lease(id, route, requestTimeout, state);
        return new LeaseRequest() {
            @Override
            public ConnectionEndpoint get(Timeout timeout) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
                acquire();
                try {
                    return lease.get(timeout);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    semaphore.release();
                    throw e;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public boolean cancel() {
                return lease.cancel();
            }
        };
    }

    private void acquire() throws InterruptedException, DeadlineTimeoutException {
        if (Timeout.isPositive(timeout)) {
            Deadline deadline = Deadline.calculate(timeout);
            if (!semaphore.tryAcquire(timeout.getDuration(), timeout.getTimeUnit())) {
                throw DeadlineTimeoutException.from(deadline);
            }
        } else {
            semaphore.acquire();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void release(ConnectionEndpoint endpoint, Object newState, TimeValue validDuration) {
        try {
            delegate.release(endpoint, newState, validDuration);
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

    // ...remaining delegates
}
```